# How to hide form_dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to hide form drop down after second selection, because that second combo box it already selected in earlier. Currently i make it to be like this.

```
$data['year'] = NULL;
```

but what i need is that variable is disappear after is selected the dropdown 1.

[image]

Below is my code.

Controller

```
function carbyyear() {
    $arrCaryear = $this->modelRegister->loadcaryear();

    $arrcaryear[''] = 'Please Select';
    foreach ($arrCaryear as $caryears) {
        $arrcaryear[$caryears->year] = $caryears->year;
    }

    $data['year'] = $arrcaryear;

    $this->load->view('abc',$data); 
}

function ajax_car_make() {

   if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['year'])) {

        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $arrMakes = $this->modelRegister->loadcarmake($year);

        //print_r($arrModels);
        $arrmakes[''] = 'Please Select';
        foreach ($arrMakes as $makes) {
            $arrmakes[$makes->make] = $makes->make;
        }

        print form_dropdown('make',$arrmakes);

        $data['year'] = NULL;

        $this->load->view('abc',$data); 

        } else {
        redirect('site');
    }   
}

function ajax_car_model() {

   if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['make'])) {

        $make = $_POST['make'];
        $arrModels = $this->modelRegister->loadmodelfrombrand($make);

        //print_r($arrModels);
        $arrmodels[''] = 'Please Select';
        foreach ($arrModels as $models) {
            $arrmodels[$models->model] = $models->model;
        }

        print form_dropdown('model',$arrmodels);
    } else {
        redirect('site');
    }   
}
```

View

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="body">
            <article>
                <table style="margin:0 auto;width:50%" >
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="50">
                            <div id="yearcombox">
                            <?php 

                                    $js = 'id="year" onChange="showMake(this);;"';
                                    echo form_dropdown('year',$year); 

                            ?>
                            </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="50"><div id="makecombox"></div> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="50"><div id="modelcombox"></div> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
             </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                 $(document).ready(function () { 
                    $('#yearcombox select').change(function () {
                        var selYear = $(this).val();
                        console.log(selYear);
                        $.ajax({   
                            url: "ajax_car_make", 
                            async: false,
                            type: "POST", 
                            data: "year="+selYear, 
                            dataType: "html", 
                            beforeSend: function(data) {
                                        $('#makecombox').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/template/images/loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                                    },                        
                            success: function(data) {

                                $('#makecombox').html(data);

                            },
                        })
                    });
                });

                $(document).ready(function () { 
                    $('#makecombox select').change(function () {
                        var selMake = $(this).val();
                        console.log(selMake);
                        $.ajax({   
                            url: "ajax_car_model", 
                            async: false,
                            type: "POST", 
                            data: "make="+selMake, 
                            dataType: "html", 
                            beforeSend: function(data) {
                                        $('#modelcombox').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/template/images/loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                                    },                        
                            success: function(data) {

                                $('#modelcombox').html(data);

                            },
                        })
                    });
                });



    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What you are trying to ask? Nothing is clear.

Comment: Hi @vinie, after selection the drop down, it shown another dropdown, but i dont want that empty dropdown is shown

Comment: Then why it is empty. fetch data for that combo box

Comment: actually i want to remove that one, that one appear because i throw in a same view, i cannot remove the dropdown since i need on a first trigger

Comment: very confusing.. You want to fetch data for 3rd combo box or you want to remove that box?

Comment: Ok you are doing it wrong way. In ajax response send only your combobox value instead of loading view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to load view in ajax response

```
function ajax_car_make()
{
   if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['year'])) {
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $arrMakes = $this->modelRegister->loadcarmake($year);
    //print_r($arrModels);
    $arrmakes[''] = 'Please Select';
    foreach ($arrMakes as $makes) {
        $arrmakes[$makes->make] = $makes->make;
    }
    echo form_dropdown('make',$arrmakes);

    } else {
    echo false;
}
```

}

Change `$('#makecombox select').change(function () {`

to

```
$('body').on('change','#makecombox select',function () {
```